# Making a GUI using Cygwin

Tags: qt, user-interface, cygwin, tk-toolkit

I want to make a GUI for my c++ console application I have in cygwin.

I can't find a straight forward guide to do this.

The two libraries that I've come across so far are Qt and TCL/Tk.

A simple tutorial getting a 'hello world' style gui up and running in cygwin would go a long way.

Comment: Thankfully, your GUI doesn't need to use Cygwin :)

Comment: Cygwin is a library providing POSIX API functionality, and a collection of tools that use that library.  It doesn't provide manuals or tutorials for all those tools - just enables them to run on Windows.